# How to increase size of UILabel Automatically adding any text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I am using `UILabel` for showing text. I am giving small `UILabel` size and a lot of text in the label. My intension is to give a lot of text in small label automatically label sizes also adjusted automatically, how to achieve this functionality? Any one please help me. I am new for iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With autolayout or without autolayout

Comment: Do you want the label to scroll horizontally automatically?

Comment: no,if iam adding more text in UIlabel ,Automatically label size also increasing vertically  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method of **UILabel**,

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```